C# Application gets stuck by a blocked serial connection due to Arduino board having an internal exception after an established COM port connection
I have an issue which seems to be a big unknown to anyone on the internet, where my Windows application gets stuck when a serial connection is interrupted by the board's internal exception.
Here is the simplest example of the issue:
Simplest C# code, opening a COM port connection.
internal static class Program
{
    private static SerialPortStream _serialPort;

    static void Main()
    {
        _serialPort = new SerialPortStream("COM6", 9600, 8, Parity.None, StopBits.One);
        _serialPort.Open();
    }
}

Arduino board code, which will simulate an internal exception after a small delay.
void loop()
{
  delay(500); //We wait 0.5 seconds to allow the COM port connection to "Successfully" be established, and so the .Open() call in C# won't throw an exception.
  
  //We create an internal exception, in this instance we try to set an array size to a negative value
  int index = -4; 
  byte* serialData = new byte[index];
}

This is a very simple way to re-create this issue.
Some notable info:

I am using a Raspberry Pi Pico module (RP2040 Zero)
The RP2040 is USB-C connected, its serial ports run through USB.
I am using 'RJCP.IO.Ports' for COM port communication on C# side. I also don't think it's the problem of the library, because I noticed that Visual Studio Code's terminal, also gets stuck when it's trying to establish a serial read communication.
I've tried calling the 'Open()' method inside a different Task and BackgroundWorker, in both cases, even though the application is not frozen, I cannot close the application until I reset the board through its onboard switch (Actually, I've realised the program will close after around 1 min of me trying to close it).
I know I can 'fix' this in Arduino code, but the point of this question is to be able to handle such case in the C# application (E.G. You will not always be the creator of whatever module you posses). I don't think a simple board should cease any control within the host.

Thank you to anyone who helps!

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Have you considered to run the Connection in a thread and kill the thread after a certain timeout if the connection cannot be established?
with threads you have good controll over abortion, even if it is stuck

You say your program "gets stuck" - but you don't say exactly where it gets stuck (but I'm guessing you mean inside the .Open() call?). BTW, SerialPortStream looks like a third-party library, so this could be a bug (or by-design) in that code rather than in .NET. I'll say that I generally recommend against using any libraries that try to simplify or abstract-away things like IO (for reasons I won't go into) but I recommend you try using Win32's device-handles directly, that way you can try using overlapped-IO which should solve this problem.

@Dai, this was already discussed here... The whole discussion was moved to this chat -> link for whatever reason, like Dharman stated above, but yes, the thread gets stuck on 'Open()' call, and no it's not the issue of the library, it also happens using any other library and Win32 API directly.

@DenisSchaf I tried aborting a background worker, I didn't bother with aborting a 'Thread' class, but I will try it, although ultimately I don't really like such solution, but equally I'm not really sure it will work as even Task Manager cannot close that process when this happens.

@Velox is this started happening recently? I have been working with com port in net application for a few years now with no problems only recently started having some issues when closing/opening poorts so just curious

@Vladimir, well I'm not sure what would you call 'Recently' and I'm not even sure if I can really say because I started working on this only few weeks ago, before I didn't touch COM ports much.

Let's look at this problem at various levels.
At the first level (device), an exception happens.
At the second level (serial port, device side) that exception means no data is sent. The exception itself is invisible.
At the third level (serial port, PC side) no data arrives. This is not at all exceptional.
At the fourth level (serial driver, PC side) the Windows I/O subsystem works asynchronously. Every command is accepted almost immediately, and only the biggest problems cause an immediate error. Most errors are detected after a while. Common behavior like "bytes being read" are returned asynchronously, as they happen.
At the fifth layer, (synchronous API) Windows can translate synchronous calls to asynchronous I/O, simply by waiting for I/O to happen. (Assuming it happens at all - not a given for serial ports).
At the sixth layer, your C# program is using a synchronous API to access the serial port, and it's doing so from the thread that's also responsible for the UI. Hence, when that thread waits for data, everything stops. Or, you use a background thread, but then that background thread blocks.
The problem here is that you need to cancel the I/O operation. The CancelIoEx function does this, but you'll need to get the HANDLE from your   SerialPortStream

Thank you for that advice, I that is one of the best leads anyone was able to give me here. I've tried 'CancelIoEx' like you said, but for some reason it always returns false... Which means the COM port was not closed, and I'm pretty sure it returns an error code which explains that it couldn't find a specified file which in this instance is the COM port, connection... Which makes me wonder if it's actually not open as far as windows is concerned, but it has to be connected somehow.... I'm going to have to play around with it more, I just didn't have the time past few days.

Might also be the handle that I'm getting could it be possible the wrong one? I don't think it is, as I'm getting it from 'CreateFileA()' function.

@Velox: You need the handle from SerialPortStream, not some other handle.

You can't get a handle from SerialPortStream, I cannot use the library if I want to use your approach, hence why I had to go back to Win32API and basically create a port connection process myself where I can retrieve the handle.
